# Who is the commentary on Sefer Orech Apayim?

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, authorship

On the bottom of the sefer there is a commentary by the name "V'Yosef Avraham". Does anyone know who wrote this? S[ee picture below from HebrewBooks.org](https://hebrewbooks.org/36225) [image]

Comment: Could you also provide a link? Also, please place relevant information in the body of your post, not just in the title.

Comment: I think i did write in the body.

Comment: The title page sounds like both were written by the same author.

Answer (score 3):

According to this site [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D) it was the author of the sefer Erech Apayim i.e. Rav Avraham Yellin himself (see also [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F)), who wrote the notes under the name V'Yosef Avraham:

> בשולי הספר, כתב המחבר הערות והרחבות בשם ויוסף אברהם אשר מרחיבות את הנושא הנדון, מביאות מקורות, דוגמאות, הסברים, וכד', אולם הן לא הודפסו בכל המהדורות.
>
> In the margins of the book, the author wrote notes and extensions in the name of V'Yosef Avraham which expand on the subject in question. He brings sources, examples, explanations, etc., but they have not been printed in all editions.